# Go up on the deck or go up on deck

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know why we do not say: *let's go up on **the deck***

but we say *let's go up **on deck***.

Or why don't we say:

*Peter stayed below the deck*

but we say *Peter stayed below deck*?

**Deck** is not general here but why we do not mention article *the* before it?

Comment: _On deck_ has been a standard phrase for a long time, probably because orders given on board ship needed to be as brief and clear as possible. Anyway, each 'layer' in a ship is a deck. I think the usual expression is _below decks_.

Comment: Thank you dear .

Comment: Are you in a boat or a house?

Comment: Maybe comparable to _on shore_?